# property not found on object type

Tags: objective-c

I have a class that looks like the following.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface JAMToDoItem : NSObject



@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *itemName;
@property BOOL * completed;
@property (readonly) NSDate * CreactionDate;
//-(void)MarkAsCompleted:(BOOL)IsComplete onDate:(NSDate*)date;

@end
```

JAMToDoItem.m file

```
    //
//  JAMToDoItem.m
//  ToDoList
//
//  Created by juanabreu on 2/15/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 juanabreu. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JAMToDoItem.h"


@interface JAMToDoItem()
//@property NSDate *completionDate;

@end



@implementation JAMToDoItem


@end
```

i then try to access the propertys in this class like the following and im getting an error

```
    //
//  JAMToDoList.m
//  ToDoList
//
//  Created by juanabreu on 2/15/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 juanabreu. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JAMToDoList.h"
#import "JAMToDoItem.h"



@interface JAMToDoList ()
@property NSMutableArray *toDoItems;

//@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *itemName;
@end

@implementation JAMToDoList
//@synthesize itemName;

-(IBAction)unwindToRootVC:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{



}



- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //instatiate the array;
    self.toDoItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self LoadInitialData];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


-(void)LoadInitialData{

    JAMToDoItem *TheItem = [[JAMToDoItem alloc]init];
    TheItem.itemName =@"Buy Milk";

}





- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 0;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return 0;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a story board-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}

 */

@end
```

Note: LoadInitialData  is being implemented on a another class and im trying to instatiate JAMToDoItem property. I'm basically following the tutorial written by APPLE located [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/RoadMapiOS.pdf). At the top of my todolist class i do have the `#import "JAMToDoItem.h"` which is the class the contains the propertys im trying to set, and where im getting the error.

so the error i end up with

```
Property 'itemName' not found on object of type 'JAMToDoItem *'
```

What I'm I missing?

Comment: Please add more code. Without the access to the property,does the error appear?

Comment: gran33 i added the full class that is making call  let me know what other code you would like to see. the error does not appear without trying to access the property.

Comment: Please don't capitalize method and variable names.

Comment: ok thank nhgrif im basically following a tutorial, simply doing what Apple themselves is showing me.

Comment: put your code on dropbox or some where(we will check). there is nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: Can u add the JAMToDoItem.m as well

Comment: thanks pawan ill do it now.

Comment: gran i added the .m file for JAMTodoItem.

Comment: full project https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=C76E2F30A33869C9&id=C76E2F30A33869C9%21136 is the todolist folder.

Comment: i have found this @interface JAMToDoItem : UIViewController, you have two JAMToDoItem in code on is NSObject & one is UIViewController . just a mess with code. just command +click on JAMToDoItem. you will find it.

Comment: i have cleaned it . here is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lk1joyo20wbgqtz/ToDoList%202.zip)

Comment: @user677275 always organize your code, otherwise you will get in mess like this again.  good luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD:

The reason is that there is other `JAMToDoItem.h` file with

```
//
//  JAMToDoItem.h
//  ToDoList
//
//  Created by juanabreu on 2/15/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 juanabreu. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface JAMToDoItem : UIViewController


@end
```

You can find it by Command+left click on

```
#import "JAMToDoItem.h"
```

It is located `ToDoList/ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.h`, and that one that you show us located at

```
ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.h
```

1. Delete references to `JAMToDoItem.h` and `JAMToDoItem.m` in you project (select and hit delete)
2. Delete files  `ToDoList/ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.h` and  `ToDoList/ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.m`
3. Move files from  `ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.h` and `ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.m` to `ToDoList/ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.h` and  `ToDoList/ToDoList/JAMToDoItem.m`
4. Select them and re-add to the project

Comment: i feel like such a donkey. thank you i simply dragged the files from one directory to the other when i was in xcode and it must have created a copy tuff lesson to learn. thank you !